# What are the minimum hardware specifications required to run an EOS blockchain?

Tags: block-producer, node, hardware

What are the minimum hardware requirements to *run* an EOS blockchain in terms of CPU power, RAM, etc?

Comment: is it possible to run EOS on portable devices like raspberry pi or something like that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EOSIO can run with very little memory, less than 100MB + shared memory file size.  The requirements for the shared memory file depends upon the state of your local application (number of users, etc).

Answer (score 4):

I was able to **run** Single Node Testnet on Ubuntu using Docker on my machine with around **2GB RAM** without problem (as **bytemaster** said it requires little memory actually).

The **CPU** and **Disk Space** are not mentioned explicitly. I guess you will need decent disk space once the blockchain increases in size.
Also, probably it's good idea to compare the hardware specifications of the current block producers.

If you use Docker the requirements to **build** the images are **7GB RAM** (see: [Docker Requirement](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/master/Docker/README.md#docker-requirement) and [GH-2355](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/pull/2355/files)).

In case you want to **build** it natively you can find the requirements on their [official Wiki](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/wiki/Local-Environment#system-requirements-all-platforms) (thanks John Haager for clarification)

Comment: These are the requirements to **build** the software, not run the blockchain.  It has been mentioned on the Telegram channel several times that the requirements to run the nodeos software is less than the requirements to build it.

Comment: Note that the wiki is out of date with its build requirements. It is actually only 7 GB, and you can get away with 4 GB if your machine only has 2 cores (I did this on an Ubuntu Chomebook). I mentioned this https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/2992 and https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/pull/2355 but this issue was closed/ignored without any resolution.

Answer (score 0):

You can build and run with as little as **2 Cores** and **4GB of RAM**:

[Can I build EOSIO with less than 7GB of RAM? | Answer: Yes](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/1379/can-i-build-eosio-with-less-than-7gb-of-ram-answer-yes)