# Can I build EOSIO with less than 7GB of RAM? | Answer: Yes

Tags: ram, build, requirements

### [System Requirements](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/install-nodeos) (all platforms)

```
7GB RAM free required
20GB Disk free required
```

I was going to ask this question because I didn't see it on here, but I actually wound up figuring it out myself, so I thought I would share.  You can actually edit any of the build shell scripts to a lower RAM limit.  I'm using an old Mac with 4GB of RAM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Minimum requirements:**

```
4GB RAM 
2 cores
```

The auto build script (`./eosio_build.sh`) capures your OS and selects the build script in `~/eos/scripts/` for your OS.  You can `nano` your OS's build shell and perform the change in the photos below.

```
cd ~/eos/scripts    
sudo nano eosio_build_ubuntu.sh
```

---

### Ubuntu:

[image]

### Mac:

[image]

### Fedora

[image]

### Amazon

[image]

### Centos

[image]

[**I got the photos from this Github issue**](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/pull/2355)

---

If you get the error [**"Mac OS 10.13.3 build error "path mongo-cxx-driver already exists"**](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/3197) do:

```
sudo rm -rf /tmp/mongo*
cd /path/to/eos
rm -rf build/
git pull
git submodule update --init --recursive
./eosio_build.sh
```